# Hyperledger fabric with M1 Macbook

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, apple-m1

I am using hyperledger fabric 2.2 on the intel chip Mac Pro right now.
However, I am look forward to buy a new Macbook Pro with m1 chip soon in the future.

I have searched lot of communities and official website to check the hyperledger fabric support m1 chip Macbook Pro.

Anyone know does the m1 work with hyperledger fabric? and
if you it does not support, do you know why not?

Please let know any small information about the concern.
Thank you.

[https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-18389?jql=text%20~%20%22m1%22](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-18389?jql=text%20%7E%20%22m1%22)

this is what I officially checked that m1 is not supportive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperledger Fabric does not currently support ARM architecture, however as M1 MacBooks includes Rosetta2 you can continue to use the `amd64` architecture images and binaries. See
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues/2994
for some details